# How do I get words from a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I wanted to get the words from a cell. For example, cell A2 has a value of "My name is jayson". I wanted to get the words: "name" & "jayson". I want to exclude words with less than 3 characters. How do I do it using a formula/function in excel?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the results to look like, e.g., do you want "name jayson" in one cell?

Comment: one in each cell, for example the result can be in the second sheet: A1: name, A2: jayson. I will use the value later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should be run from the sheet that contains your data to be splice. I have assumed that you are working in column A

The code

1. Uses a regular expression to remove all alphanumeric strings less or equal to 3 characters
2. Dumps a revised set of strings to a newly created sheet
3. Splits these strings using excel's "Text to Columns"

Variant arrays are used to make this an efficient process

*{Update: added no loop version}*

[image]

**`Original Code`**

```
    Sub Spliced()
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim objRegex
        Dim X
        Dim lngRow As Long

        Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
        Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[a1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        Set ws2 = Sheets.Add

        X = rng1.Value2
        Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With objRegex
            .Pattern = "\b\w{1,3}\b"
            .Global = True
        End With

        For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)
            X(lngRow, 1) = Application.Trim(objRegex.Replace(X(lngRow, 1), vbNullString))
        Next

        ws2.Range(rng1.Address) = X
        ws2.Columns("A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
    End Sub
```

**`Updated:No loops`**

```
Sub Spliced_NoLoops()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim objRegex
    Dim strDelim As String
    Dim strOut As String

    strDelim = "||"
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[a1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    strOut = Join(Application.Transpose(rng1), strDelim)

    Set ws2 = Sheets.Add
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "\b\w{1,3}\b"
        .Global = True
    End With

    ws2.Range(rng1.Address) = Application.Transpose(Split(Application.Trim(objRegex.Replace(strOut, vbNullString)), "||"))
    ws2.Columns("A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                   TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: The `.TextToColumns` in your code gave me an idea. How about using `.TextToColumns` first and then using autofilter to remove words which are less than 4 characters? Will save time as we will then not have to loop? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @SiddharthRout because you would have to autofilter then clear all the used columns, which could be considerable depending on the length of the test strings. I think the variant array will be quicker - although probably splitting hairs given the likely record size

Comment: Hmmm, You have a point there... It's a shame that we have to loop whether using RegExp or Split() as bernie suggested :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Using `Split` is a secondary loop though (through each individual string) which the Regexp avoids.

Comment: Yes you are right :) What I meant was both the methods use loop. I am still thinking of a way which can avoid any kind of loop :)

Comment: I have a logic which I am trying to follow, and if I succeed (unsure if it will work) then I guess that would be the fastest way to achieve the above :) Still testing.

Comment: @SiddharthRout looking forward to it :)

Comment: Ok it is done. Just trying to sort out a minor issue. Would love to discuss it with you if you are available for a quick chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9501/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-brettdj)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I added a no loop version

Answer (score 2):

You don't show what you've tried, so coding from the ground up...
Pass the cell-to-split's range to this function which does roughly the following:

1. Create a [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) into which we will put any strings with len > 2
2. split the cell contents into an array. ( [variants can contain arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163618%28v=office.10%29.aspx) )
3. evaluate length of each segment and add to collection strings w/ length > 2
4. the return value of the function is a collection w/ qualifying strings

Please always save your work before running any VBA. Cheers, and happy coding.

```
function splitter(byref rng as range) 
    dim return_value as collection
    set return_value = new collection

    dim split_result as variant 
    dim idx as integer 

    split_result = split(rng.value, " ") 

    for idx = lbound(split_result) to ubound(split_result) 
        if len(split_result(idx)) > 2 then  
            return_value.add(split_result(idx))
        end if
    next  
    splitter = return_value
end function
```

I do not have a Windows nor Mac OS at hand to test, but the syntax should be correct if not nearly so.

Comment: it's giving me `#NAME?`. I used the function as: `=splitter(C5:C6)`

Comment: ah, this is a user-defined function (UDF). please see "Accessing Your Custom Functions" here ( http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut01.htm ) And please do accept my apologies, I must run but will check back in sometime tomorrow. Best of luck with your project.